# extract every n row in a matrix to another matrix in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, extract

I'm a total beginner to matlab and I'm currently writing a script for extracting data from a thermographic video.

Firstly the video is cut in separate frames. The first frame is opened as a sample picture to define the coordinates of sampling points. The goal is then to select the rgb values of those defined coordinates from a set of frames and save them into a matrix.

Now I have a problem separating the matrix to n smaller matrices.
e.g I'm defining the number of points to be selected to n=2 , with a picture count of 31. Now it returns a matrix stating the rgb codes for 31 pictures, each at 2 points, in  a 62x3 double matrix...

Now I want to extract the 1st, 3rd, 5th....etc... row to a new matrix...this should be done in a loop, according to the number of n points...e.g 5 points on each picture equals 5 matrices, containing values of 31 pictures....

**this is an extract of my code to analyse the pictures, it returns the matrix 'values'**

```
files = dir('*.jpg');
num_files = numel(files);

images = cell(1, num_files);
cal=imread(files(1).name);

n = input('number of selection points?: ');

imshow(cal);

[x,y] = ginput(n);

eval(get(1,'CloseRequestFcn'))

%# x = input('x-value?: ');   manual x selection
%# y = input('y-value?: ');   manual y selection

for k = 1:num_files
    images{k} = imread(files(k).name); 
end

matrix=cell2mat(images);
count=(0:size(matrix,1):size(matrix,1)*num_files);

for k = 1:num_files
    a(k)= mat2cell(impixel(matrix,x+count(k),y));
end

values = cat(1,a{:})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easy fix

Do you mean that if you have:

```
n = 2;
k = 2; % for example
matrix = [1 2 3;
          4 5 6;
          7 8 9;
          8 7 6];
```

you want it to become

```
b{1} = [1 2 3;
        7 8 9];
b{2} = [4 5 6;
        8 7 6];
```

This can be easily done with:

```
 for ii = 1:n
     b{ii} = matrix(1:n:end,:);
 end
```

### Better fix

Of course it's also possible to just reshape your data matrix and use that instead of the smaller matrices: (continuing with my sample data ^^)

```
>> d=reshape(matrix',3,2,[]);
>> squeeze(d(:,1,:))

ans =

     1     7
     2     8
     3     9
>> squeeze(d(:,2,:))

ans =

     4     8
     5     7
     6     6
```

### Good practice

Or, my preferred choice: save the data immediately in an easy to access way. Here I think it will be an matrix of size: [num_files x num_points x 3]

If you want all the first points:

```
rgb_data(:,1,:)
```

only the red channel of those points:

```
rgb_data(:,1,1)
```

and so on. 
I think this is possible with this:

```
rgb_data = zeros(num_files, num_points, 3);
for kk = 1:num_files
    rgb_data(kk,:,:) = impixel(images{kk},x+count(k),y);
end
```

But I don't understand the complete meaning of your code (eg: why `matrix=cell2mat(images)` ??? and then of course:

```
count=(0:size(matrix,1):size(matrix,1)*num_files);
```

is just `count=0:num_files;`
so I'm not sure what would come out of `impixel(matrix,x+count(k),y)` and I used images{k} :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, the cell is created with the right dimension and the argument 1:n:end,: sounds plausible, but it only fills the cell array with the very first rgb value....

Comment: if size(matrix)==[k*n x 3], the colon operator `:` should select the whole row. If you say it isn't (you said rgb values are stored in rows), you should check the size of `matrix`

Comment: Ok, sorry I got it, your code only refers to the first value in each picture and replicates it to the value of n, since ii=1:n, so for n=4 it simply copys the cells 4 times,taking the values from the first row, because 1:4:end = 1

Comment: yes, correct
You said you wanted to separate the numbers in `matrix` to different smaller matrices. You can also use b1, b2, b3, b4, etc. but it's easier to use and later expand to use the cell notation: b{1}, b{2}, etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see how this leads me to a cell array which stores the first points in b{1,1}, the second points in b{1,2}....Sorry for complaining, I've been stuck with this part for 2 days now and still haven't found a suitable solution..                                                                                                                              edit:great reshape :)